# Way to Read/Write photos from the blackberry device

Tags: blackberry, bitmap, save, photo

I'm trying to create a blackberry app in which I need to take a photo that the user has saved on or taken on their blackberry and then add it to another photo and save the photo so that when the user goes into their saved photos then the new photo is available. I am currently struggling with how to access the user's photos and then saving the new photo in a place where the user can get it and eventually add it as their background image of their phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to read Images from Device.

```
public void checkImages(String imagePath) {
    String path = "";
    if (imagePath.equals(""))
        path = "file:///SDCard/";
    else
        path = imagePath;
    try {
        FileConnection fileConnection = (FileConnection)Connector.open(path);
        if (fileConnection.isDirectory()) {
            Enumeration directoryEnumerator = fileConnection.list("*", true);
            while(directoryEnumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
                contentVector.addElement(directoryEnumerator.nextElement());
            }
            fileConnection.close();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < contentVector.size() ; i ++) {
                String name = (String) contentVector.elementAt(i);
                checkImages(path + name);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                fileConnection.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Code to save image to device..

```
private void saveBitmap(int picIndex, Bitmap bmp) 
{

    String PHOTO_DIR = System.getProperty ("fileconn.dir.photos"); 
    String EXTENSION = ".bmp";
    String filePath = PHOTO_DIR + picIndex + EXTENSION;        

    try
    {
        FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(filePath, Connector.READ_WRITE); 

        if(fconn.exists())
           fcomm.delete();

        fconn.create();

        OutputStream outputStream = fconn.openOutputStream();

        PNGEncodedImage encodedImage =  PNGEncodedImage.encode(bmp);
        byte[] imageBytes = encodedImage.getData();                   
       outputStream.write(imageBytes);
       outputStream.close();
        fconn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("  Exception while saving Bitmap:: "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

and get help from [Read/Write Image](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-save-bitmap-image-on-device/m-p/237869#M37543).